# NodeJs: Collecting data across multiple "data" events using http.get()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to collect multiple "data" events using http.get() and append them to a string and print it to the console. The last two console.log() statements always print 0 and an empty string. But the console.log() inside the http.get() prints all the received data correctly. The string str is a global variable so no scope problems. Then why does the last line print an empty string?

```
// JavaScript File
var http = require('http');

var str = '';

http.get(process.argv[2], function(response){
    response.on('error', console.error);
    response.on('data', function(data){
       str += data.toString();
    });
    response.on('end', function(){
        console.log(str); //works fine, prints the received data
    );
}).on('error', console.error);

console.log(str.length); // prints 0
console.log(str); // prints empty string
```

Comment: This is asynchronous java script .. meaning your JavaScript doesn't wait for your previous function to complete . It executes the next statement asynchronously . I would suggest use a call back after your response completes like the one you already have .. but if you want that value outside of ur http get . Consider using promises

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common gotcha when working with node. You are dealing with an asynchronous request when you use `http.get()`. What this means is you final `console.log()` statement will be called before the callback functions within `http.get().`

With your code the order of events goes something like this:

- define `str`
- initiate `http.get()`
- final two `console.log()` statements
- receive data from `http.get()`
- add to `str`
- `console.log()` inside the `http.get()` callbacks

So everything is working, you are just asking for the data before you have received it.